# "Error: Can't open display: 172.28.80.1:0" in WSL2

Tags: xorg, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I've tried "all the things" from SO, github, etc. I'm using MobaXTerm.

In my .bashrc I have

```
export DISPLAY="$(/sbin/ip route | awk '/default/ { print $3 }'):0"
```

Which results in

```
(base) balter@ORLT1072346:~$ echo $DISPLAY
172.28.80.1:0
```

In CMD `ipconfig` gives

```
Ethernet adapter vEthernet (WSL):

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::7442:c2c6:5b47:11ff%41
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 172.28.80.1
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.240.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :
```

At the top of my moba terminal it says "Your DISPLAY is set to 192.168.1.14:0.0"  So I"ve tried `DISPLAY=192.168.1.14:0.0`, which results in the same "Can't open display..." error.

My resolv.conf reads:

```
(base) balter@ORLT1072346:~$ cat /etc/resolv.conf
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.8.4
```

I had to do this an override the auto-generated one because I wasn't getting internet.

Oh, and my `/etc/ssh/sshd_conf` has

```
(base) balter@ORLT1072346:~$ cat /etc/ssh/sshd_config | grep X11
X11Forwarding yes
#X11DisplayOffset 10
X11UseLocalhost yes
#       X11Forwarding no
```

Comment: Did you know that WSL is not intended for a desktop environment or GUI applications?  WSL is intended to allow you to use Linux command line utilities on Windows.  If you want a Ubuntu desktop on Windows, you should use a VM like VirtualBox. See: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/faq#can-i-run-all-linux-apps-in-wsl

Comment: You are entitled to your opinion, but tens of thousands, if not hundreds of thousands of people use X11 apps with WSL. These include things such as RStudio, Spyder, and VS Code. Third-party applications are specifically set up to run WSL and provide an X-server. Perhaps you should explore this option and discover the valuable benefits for yourself.

Comment: The link is from Microsoft's documentation...

Comment: How are you connecting to the WSL?  I am wondering this because if you connect via ssh to a host without specifying the `-X` or `-Y` the export $DISPLAY is blank.  You may not need to set the export DISPLAY in your .bashrc file.

Comment: @Nmath -- [here are the github issues](https://github.com/Microsoft/WSL/issues?q=x11) for WSL regarding X11. Perhaps if the WSL developers aren't calling people out for wanting to use X11, you could back off a little.

Comment: @Terrance, I'm not connecting to the WSL. I'm running WSL in a terminal program that has a built-in X server (MobaXTerm).

Comment: Sorry about that, I had to back myself up and see what you are talking about.  I installed the MobaXTerm on my system here and when I run it I can run graphical applications as well as a full Xfce4 Desktop in it.  I did not though set the export DISPLAY settings anywhere in my installation.  I did install xserver-xorg into my WSL2 installation.  When I run the `echo $DISPLAY` mine returns `127.0.0.1:0.0`.

Comment: The lack of DNS with the default `resolve.conf` settings may be a clue.  I'm fairly sure that the default is to use the provided Hyper-V virtual host interface.  If you aren't able to connect to that, then it's likely that the same networking issue is preventing the communication with Moba's X server.

Comment: Personally, I'd recommend moving this over to [Super User](https://superuser.com).  It really has nothing to do with Ubuntu itself.  I would expect that you would see exactly the same problem if you add a Kali (or Debian, or Alpine) instance in WSL.  I believe you can flag your own question and ask a moderator to move it (as long as there are no upvoted answers).

Comment: @abalter Were you able to find a solution for it? I am facing similar issues.